# How to render a view that disapear after few seconds (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

Wanted to render a view that shows current page/number of pages

(when i touch the image, it renders this view) i used touchable opacity,but when touched nothing happens

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={()=>{return <ShowPagination/>}}
   style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', bottom:40}}
   onStartShouldSetResponder={(e) => {
     return e.nativeEvent.touches.length < 2 && scaleValue.current <= 1;
   }}
 >
   <Image
     source={source}
     resizeMode="contain"
     style={styles.image}
   />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is the view i want to render

```
const ShowPagination = () => {
  return(
    <View style={paging_style.paging_container}>
      <Text style={paging_style.text}>NP/TP</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant return a component in onPress, thats not how it works,

you should involve state in order to achieve this,

```html
const [ showPagination, setShowPagination] = useState(false)
```

then in touchable opacity, setShowPagination to true

```html
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={()=> setShowPagination(true) }
              style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', bottom:40}}
              onStartShouldSetResponder={(e) => {
                return e.nativeEvent.touches.length < 2 && scaleValue.current <= 1;
              }}
            >
              <Image
                source={source}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={styles.image}
              />

          </TouchableOpacity>
```

then somewhere inside component as per requirement, place ShowPagination like below

```html
{ showPagination && <ShowPagination /> }
```

now last thing, you want to hide  after few seconds, you can set setTimeout in useEffect

```html
useEffect(() => {
  if (showPagination) {
    // 1000 for 1 second
    setTimeout(() => setShowPagination(false), 1000)
  }
}, [showPagination])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this, maybe can clear your thoughts.

```
const [ showPagination, setShowPagination] = useState(false)



<>
    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() setShowPagination(prev => !prev)}}
       // ...rest of props
       > 
       // .... rest of component
    </TouchableOpacity>
    
    // When render will trigger the useEffect of ShowPagination Component
    { showPagination && <ShowPagination delay={1000} /> } 
    </>
....
```

> ShowPagination.tsx

```
import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ShowPagination = (props) => {
  const showPaginationRef = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

  const animate = useCallback(
    (toValue = 0) => {
      Animated.timing(showPaginationRef, {
        toValue,
        duration: 200,
        isInteraction: false,
        useNativeDriver: false,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      }).start();
    },
    [showPaginationRef],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => animate(), props.delay);
  }, [animate]);

  const opacity = showPaginationRef.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
  });
  return (
    <Animated.View style={[paging_style.paging_container, { opacity }]}>
      <Text style={paging_style.text}>NP/TP</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```